# Haskell Unzip With Fold

Tags: haskell, unzip, fold

I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom unzip function in Haskell using a custom version of fold (basically works as foldl) but I've become stuck. I can get it to

```
unzip' :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
unzip' = fold (\x->([x!!0],[x!!1])) ([],[])
```

But that errors out with:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
              with actual type ‘(Integer, Integer)’
• In the first argument of ‘tail’, namely ‘(1, 2)’
  In the expression: tail (1, 2)
  In an equation for ‘it’: it = tail (1, 2)
• Relevant bindings include
    it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:114:1)
```

From what I figure, `x` is `(1,2)` but I'm not sure how to further split it into 1 and 2. Here is the fold function that I am using:

```
fold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> ([a] -> b)
fold c n =
  let f [] = n
      f (x:xs) = x `c` (f xs)
  in f
```

Thank you

Comment: `!!` is for list indexing, it looks like you want to access tuple elements. You can use `fst` and `snd` functions to access the first and second elements of tuples.

Comment: N.B. Your `fold` works more like `foldr` than `foldl`. The former receives a `(a -> b -> b)` while the latter receives a `(b -> a -> b)`.

Comment: Not a pro haskellist but the error doesn't seem to match the result of running the unzip and fold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your lambda function.

Firstly, `fold` expects a `(a -> b -> b)`, so technically, a function with two arguments. Right now, your lambda only accepts 1 argument. Since your `fold` resembles `foldr` (folds from the right), the second argument should be the *accumulator* object, which collects the result from each fold.

Secondly, you are working with tuples, not lists (as [pdexter noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955660/haskell-unzip-with-fold#comment96673676_54955660)). Thus, you should use the `fst` and `snd` functions.

After some modifications to the lambda:

```
\x acc -> (fst x:fst acc, snd x:snd acc)
```

This will append the first element from each tuple to the first list of the accumulator. And the second element from each tuple to the second list of the accumulator. Some results:

```
unzip' :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
unzip' = fold (\x acc -> (fst x:fst acc, snd x:snd acc)) ([],[])

unzip' [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
([1,2,3],"abc")
```

Following [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955660/haskell-unzip-with-fold/54955822?noredirect=1#comment96674405_54955822), you can also take advantage of pattern matching in the lambda, replacing `fst` and `snd`. This may increase the strictness of the function. You can also replace `([], [])` with `mempty`, a predefined empty tuple.

```
unzip' = fold (\(x, y) (xs, ys) -> (x:xs, y:ys)) mempty
```

<sub>Tip: Before jumping into the `unzip` function, you could isolate and test out the lambda with your `fold` first.</sub>

Comment: `fst` and `snd` can be replaced with pattern matching, which ought to improve the strictness somewhat: `fold (\ (x, y) (xs, ys) -> (x : xs, y : ys)) ([], [])`. And if you prefer, `([], [])` is `mempty`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Somehow I didnt realize that it wasnt a list but in fact a tuple -_-